# How to generate HTML report with SonarQube-6.7.5

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, maven-3, jacoco

I am working on Spring4.0 Project with apache-maven-3.5.4 and Java 1.8 and would like to use SonarQube for code coverage and reports. I am using jacoco-maven-plugin 0.7.8 version plugin for that. I am able to see the details in the browser. But when I try to generate the report to HTML, I am not seeing the reports generated. I did a lot of research in Google and I followed the below

```
 mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.issuesreport.html.enable=true
```

and i added the entry in POM as well. But the reports are not generated. Kindly help me in getting this resolved. Below is my configuration in POM file.

```
 <!-- Sonar -->
 <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco- 
   it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
 <sonar.groovy.binaries>target/classes</sonar.groovy.binaries>

 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.905</version>
 </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue report plugin was [deprecated](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Issues+Report+Plugin), so this option will not work with recent versions of SonarQube. SonarQube is able to display coverage and reports via its UI, so this functionality was dropped.

Comment: I updated that and i dont see any progress with that. Still the html is not generated.

Comment: This functionality is removed from SonarQube, generating the html report is not possible anymore

Comment: @RamKarlapudi Completely unclear which HTML report you are talking about ? Like this one - https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/coverage/index.html ? Then this has absolutely nothing to do with SonarQube that has its own UI and as Tibor answered  won't give you any HTML reports about coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, don't you have an issue with your pom? I see

```
<sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco- 
   it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
```

With the default maven directory layout, the target directory is inside ${project.basidir}. I would expect an issue like "no such file or directory" when the plugin tries to generate the reports, unless it is created on the fly.

Try with

```
<sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco- 
   it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
```

or maybe even

```
<sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>target/jacoco- 
   it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
```

depending on what the parent directory is set to.

Comment: Hi Will, Thanks for the reply.I tried both the options and it did not work either case.

Comment: jacoco-it.exec is not the standard file name for jacoco execution informations. you need to set jacoco destFile the same as sonar.jacoco.itReportPath.
see [this](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html#destFile) for details. what is not very clear IMO is that the destfile parameter is related to the prepareagent goal and inflences the report goal.

Answer (score 0):

In recent version, you have to generate your own reports based on what api/issues gives you.

A simple JS script can do trick.