# SonarQube locak html report not available in new versions

Tags: sonarqube, code-analysis, sonarlint

from long time there was an warning when running sonar analysis.
[WARNING] *HTML report is deprecated. Use SonarLint CLI to have local reports of issues*
Despite of it everything worked fine ( I was using Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true command to get an html report). 
With new version there isn't any local report. 
Does anyone has the same problem? Is there any substitue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate HTML report with SonarQube-6.7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51973287/how-to-generate-html-report-with-sonarqube-6-7-5)

Comment: The question was asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51973287/how-to-generate-html-report-with-sonarqube-6-7-5/52003433?noredirect=1#comment90971680_52003433 , so I marked yours as duplicate. There is no replacement, you should use SonarQube user interface to manage your issues

Comment: Yes, but the question is, what about sonar results in preview mode? i know that I can see it when it's publish but I'm analizying every commit before it reaches to master. So I use -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview. Do you have any clue?

Comment: `sonar.analysis.mode=preview` was removed, if you want to analyze every commit in branches, you can consider Developer Edition of SonarQube (commercial)

Comment: Maybe you should just stick with the older versions, the SonarQube team wants you to buy for features that were previously free. And Sonarlint CLI has been dropped too.